# Nothing is shown after logging into Google play developer console in Opera

Tags: opera

When I try to log in to Google Play Developer Console, it asks for my email address. In the past, when I entered it, it showed the menus and I could access everything.

Since a few days, when I've logged in, I've got an empty page.

I use Opera 12.16 with ABP. I checked the source of the page and the body consists of the following:

```
<body><script>
    eval(function(p,a,c,k,e,d){e=function(c){return c.toString(36)};if(!''.replace(/^/,String)){while(c--){d[e(c)]=k[c]||e(c)}k=[function(e){return d[e]}];e=function(){return'\\w+'};c=1};while(c--){if(k[c]){p=p.replace(new RegExp('\\b'+e(c)+'\\b','g'),k[c])}}return p}('s.r(9(){2 5=a.8("y");5.w=9(){2 c=a.8("l").m(\'n\');c.k(5,0,0);2 d=c.e(0,0,5.f,1).h;2 7=[];b(2 i=0;(i<d.o);i+=4){b(2 6=0;(6<3);6++){7.v(u.q(d[i+6]))}}g(7.t(\'\'))};5.x="z/j.p"},0);',36,36,'||var|||ii|i2|result|createElement|function|document|for|||getImageData|width|eval|data||horizontal_line|drawImage|canvas|getContext|2d|length|png|fromCharCode|setTimeout|window|join|String|push|onload|src|img|gwt'.split('|'),0,{}))
  </script></body>
```

I cleared the cache, restarted the computer, nothing helped. What else should  I set?

Comment: Do you resolve this problem?

Comment: I can't. But at the moment it seems almost every Google services having problem: http://s28.postimg.org/k9nzpe0n1/google_down.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Trying to login with other browsers solves the issue with me. Funny thing is that there is no rule of thumb which browser will work - for my friend it was Firefox on Mac, while I needed to use Iron on Windows (Firefox was failing).

And it didn't have to do with plugins (I had Adblock on both Firefox and Iron).